# Smallest Value Between Two Random Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

Given two random arrays that are five integers long (and have a max value of 6 for each integer), I need a function that compares which array has the lowest integer. If the two arrays have the same lowest integer, The function compares the next two lowest, and so on. the only methods I can think of for smallestOfTwo() would take hundreds of lines of data, and too much memory. Here's what little I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] n= new int [5];
    int[] m= new int [5];

    for(int i=0; i<n.length; i++) {
        n[i]=(int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    }

    for(int x=0;x<n.length;x++) {
        m[x]=(int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    }

    System.out.println(smallestOfTwo(n,m)+" has the smallest value of the two arrays");
}

public static String smallestOfTwo(int[] x,int[] y) {
    String smallest = "unassigned";
    //help??
    if() {
        smallest = "Array n"
    }
    else
        smallest = "Array m"

    return smallest;
}
```

Comment: Sort the arrays, compare them lexicographically.

Comment: It would be easiest if you were to sort the arrays before checking for the smallest elements in each array.

Comment: "Hundreds of lines of code" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could sort the arrays first which will make the task at hand easier to solve than simply loop through the arrays and compare their values.

```
public static String smallestOfTwo(int[] n,int[] m)
{
       Arrays.sort(n);
       Arrays.sort(m);
       for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
           if(n[i] < m[i]){
               return "Array n";
           }else if(n[i] > m[i]){
               return "Array m";
           }
       }
       return "both Array n & Array m are the same";
}
```

Comment: @CooperTedstrom glad it helped. don't forget to mark as accepted if the solution has solved your problem ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the arrays using Bubble sort in a descending order, go for the last index in both. Now you have to compare these two.

Comment: There's `Arrays.sort`

Comment: I'm really sorry, I thought this was C++ post. My bad, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays Class it has a static method sort

```
Ex: int arr[]={5,3,2,1};
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

the new array will be sorted and just take the first or the last as you want (the largest or the smallest)

You can see Arrays methods in this site

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_arrays.htm